# Limitations of ajax requests when building a javascript widget api for third party sites. (like sharethis, uservoice, etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I'm creating a javascript file for a widget that third party websites will hotlink/embed (similar to sharethis, uservoice, google analytics, etc).

Suppose the javascript file is hosted at **api.myservice.com/js/foo.js** and the third party site linking to it is **example.com**, to what all domains/sub-domains can my javascript do ajax requests? (cross browser support too)

The javascript file needs to be able to communicate with the php api at **widget.myservice.com**

I am planning to host the javascript file on a CDN to accelerate delivery. Any limitations that will be caused by this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using some of the newly standardized HTTP headers to allow cross-domain requests your widget will be able to make AJAX request only to `example.com` no matter where the website downloads the script from.

There are few options how to get around this.

You can utilize the `<script>` tag instead of AJAX requests. Simply, you dynamically add the script tag with a src element pointing to `widget.myservice.com/somehting` and it will download the script, which can contain data for your widget.

Or you might distribute a server-side proxy that would make requests from `example.com` to `widget.myservice.com` and pass the response to the client.

Or you might use some of the new HTTP headers for cross browser requests, but you will be limited to only the newest browsers. Google that.